# Typescript React: How do I pass my interface as a prop into a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, refactoring, react-props

I am refactoring my code for my to-do list project, I currently have a file named "Active" (for active tasks) in my component folder.

My problem is I am having difficulty passing an interface as a prop into my component and it is returning the following error:

```
TS2741: Property 'toDos' is missing in type '{ length: number; toString(): string; toLocaleString(): string; pop(): ToDo | undefined; push(...items: ToDo[]): number; concat(...items: ConcatArray<ToDo>[]): ToDo[]; concat(...items: (ToDo | ConcatArray<...>)[]): ToDo[]; ... 30 more ...; showActive: () => void; }' but required in type '{ newTask: () => void; showActive: () => void; toDos: ToDo[]; }'.
```

I have an `ActiveTasks` function that I am trying to export to my App file. I thought that `toDos: ToDo[]` would be sufficient but it is out of scope

```
export const ActiveTasks = (props:{
    newTask: () => void
    showActive: () => void
    toDos: ToDo[]
  }) => (
    <div className="App">
        <div id="completed-task-counter">
          {toDos.length} {toDos.length === 1 ? "Active Task" : "Active Tasks"}
      </div>
</div>
```

The error message (TS2741) above is referring to the line below in my App.tsx file:

```
  if (showingActiveTasks) {
    return <ActiveTasks newTask={newTask} showActive={showActive} {...toDos} />;
  }
```

Why would I get an error if I am defining the `toDos` prop as a spread operator for the `ToDo` array and why is the `toDos.length` returning `undefined` if it is defined as a prop above?

Comment: use `toDos={toDos}`

Comment: That cleared up my error! Thank you! However, why is toDos.length out of scope in my ActiveTasks function?

Comment: you means when using `{...toDos}`? because it did not pass anything into the `toDos` prop (in `ActiveTasks`) so it becomes `undefined`

Comment: I figured it out! I entered {props.toDo.length} and my error went away! Thank you.